# Hospedagem de software online usando python e django

Tags: python, django

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno software de gestão ERP em Python e usando o framework Django, para isso tive que instalar alguns requerimentos. Como faço para hospedar esse sistema? É como um site? Quais as diferenças? Qual o melhor sistema de hospedagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um sistema de hospedagem bem simples é o [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/). Ele é bem bacana pois já facilita todo ambiente de Python.

Porém existem diversos sites que hospedam sistemas em Python e Django e que possuem ótimos guias de como fazer a implantação e deixá-los disponíveis. O [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) possui opções de baixo custo mas são servidores localizados fora do Brasil. A [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) oferece opções que podem escalar conforme sua necessidade e tem opções em São Paulo mas o custo pode variar bem mais.

Tudo depende da sua necessidade, caso esteja iniciando, indico o primeiro exemplo e com o tempo você pode migrar para hospedagens mais avançadas.

O passo a passo é um pouco longo para descrever todo aqui mas escolhendo um dos serviços de hospedagem e buscando palavras-chave de Django e hospedagem nele você deve encontrar diversos guias que te ajudam do início ao fim.